# Symfony2 ElasticSearch sort mapping errors

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

I am trying to sort the poducts by price using elastic.. However for some reason the field is not mapped and I get an error. I dont exactly know what im doing, sine this is the first time im using something like this.. Help woould be great!

In my products entity I have a simple field called base that stores the prices:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="base", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
 */
private $base;
```

My config.yml:

```
fos_elastica:
    default_manager: orm
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        app:
            index_name: app_%kernel.environment%
            types:
                product:
                    mappings:
                        id:
                            type: integer
                        adminTitle:
                            type: string
                        base:
                            type: double
                    persistence:
                        # the driver can be orm, mongodb, phpcr or propel
                        # listener and finder are not supported by
                        # propel and should be removed
                        driver: orm
                        model: Mp\ShopBundle\Entity\Product
                        provider: ~
                        listener:
                            immediate: ~
                        finder: ~
                        repository: Mp\ShopBundle\Repository\ProductRepository
                        elastica_to_model_transformer:
                            query_builder_method: findProductsBySearch
                            ignore_missing: true
```

So to get products I am using my own function:

```
    public function findProductsBySearch($data)
    {

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('o');
        $qb->addSelect('trans')->join('o.translations', 'trans');
        $qb->addSelect('gallery')->join('o.gallery', 'gallery');
        $qb->addSelect('media')->join('gallery.galleryHasMedias', 'media');
        $qb->addSelect('image')->join('media.media', 'image');
        $qb->where("LOWER(o.adminTitle) LIKE :name");
        $qb->SetParameter('name', '%'.strtolower($data).'%');
//
//        var_dump($qb);
//        die;

        return $qb;
//        return $qb->getQuery();

    }
```

PROBLEM:

When I try to sort the products found I am getting an error:

```
Parse Failure [No mapping found for [o.base] in order to sort on]
```

If to my query I add :

```
$qb->addSelect('o.base');
```

I get:

```
Cannot read property "id" from an array. Maybe you intended to write the property path as "[id]" instead.
```

Now Im stuck both ways..

P.S

I am sorting with knp paginator in my twig:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li>{{  knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Más barato', 'o.base', {'direction': 'desc'}) }}</li>
   <li>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Más caro', 'o.base', {'direction': 'asc'}) }}</li>
   <li>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Más nuevo', 'o.created_at', {'direction': 'desc'}) }}</li>
   <li>{{ knp_pagination_sortable(pagination, 'Más antiguo', 'o.created_at', {'direction': 'asc'}) }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have some caching such as redis, etc.? Have you tried `doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`?

Comment: Yes. It did not help